# Fatal error: require_once() [function.require]: Failed opening required global.php

Tags: mysql, joomla, xampp, virtuemart

I am try to open my site in locally. `xampp` is installed, but I get the following errors. How can I rectify this:

> Warning: require_once(/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/artgallery/administrator/components/com_virtuemart/classes/phpInputFilter/class.inputfilter.php) [function.require-once]: failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/artgallery/administrator/components/com_virtuemart/global.php on line 104

And:

> Fatal error: require_once() [function.require]: Failed opening required '/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/artgallery/administrator/components/com_virtuemart/classes/phpInputFilter/class.inputfilter.php' (include_path='.:/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/lib/php:/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/lib/php/pear') in /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/artgallery/administrator/components/com_virtuemart/global.php on line 104

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This Warning is not  `Failed opening required global.php`. This warning says line number 104 of `global.php` have a statement for requiring a file named `class.inputfilter.php` But, failed to load it.

This issue can occur in following cases :

```
--> File does not exists.

--> File exists but do not have READ permission.
```

**Solution :**

Go to the path :

`/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/artgallery/administrator/components/com_virtuemart/classes/phpInputFilter/`

and find the file named `class.inputfilter.php`.

If not found then get it from the fresh package of Virtuemart(Remember to check the version. Both files have to be from same Virtuemart version).

If exists then change its permissions to `644` or `755`.

Comment: ya jitendra you are right that folder is missing in local host...its a live website i am doing some offline correction once uploaded the entire directory... i hope its working fine...... thanks for your valuable feedback